# How to add dropdownlist in yii to append tag in jquery

Tags: yii

Here i am unable to add the `dropdownList` of Yii to append method in jQuery. Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tasks-add").click(function () {
        $('.tasks').append('<li class="elements"><?php echo $form->labelEx($modelAcademics, 'Academic'); ?><?php echo $form->dropDownList($modelAcademics, '[]academics', array('school', 'college'));?></li>');
    });
});
```

but i am able to add the `textField` instead of `dropdownList`. can any one help me on this ?

Comment: The dropdown list doesn't have `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the dropdown with the php code to your HTML on page load (server side), than tag it with a class with CSS property `display: none;` Than have the jQuery show it on click.Also your dropDownlist name of []academics is a bit weird, this should just be `academics`. Examples:

HTML/CSS/PHP:

```
<style type="text/css">.myDropDown { visibility: hidden; }</style.
<?php 
echo $form->labelEx($modelAcademics, 'academic');
echo $form->dropDownList($modelAcademics, 'academics', array('school', 'college'),array('class' => 'myDropDown')); 
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tasks-add").click(function () {
    $('.myDropDown').show();
});
});
```